# Upload failed for filename. The path doesn't exist

Tags: upload

I have an issue with uploading files. I got an error message:

> Upload failed for filename. Path directory structure
>   "/public_html/assets/images /" set for this resource doesn't exist.

The Path should be good, because the public_html folder is directly in the root and the /assets/images folder is in it, permissions are 777.

It worked well on my local, it stopped working when I moved the site live. All pictures uploaded on my local are displaying on the live site...I just can't upload new

Comment: Looks like there's an extra space in your path, after `images` – could that be it? If not, try to add `die($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` to your `index.php` file, to see the real public root path for your app.

Comment: Yup, the real public path was /home/html/ instead just /.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Awesome. I'll add that as an answer, then :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your public root is something else/more than just `/public_html`. Try adding the following to your `index.php` file, and refresh your site:

```
die($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Your real public root path should now display in your browser.